# Identity Server 3 with Angular 7 - Just checking a fact

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity

I have been asked to look at an existing project that uses Angular 7, .net core api's and Identity Server 4.

the task is to retrofit this so it can actually auth against our identity server 3. (using implicit client).

The person who wrote this project is no longer with the company, but has left. I have spent 2 days on this and can't get it to work.

So I guess my question is, am I wasting my time? Is it possible for an Angular 7 client authenticate against Identity Server 3 (Implicit flow)?

Update.

Other applications use the ID3 server and can authenticate on my local copy, so I am sure if there is a configurationissue it is in the Angular site. However the Angular site will auth vs id4, so this is most likely a configuration (or understanding) issue on my part.

This is my first real attempt to understand Identity Server, so I am now doubting myself as to whether implicit is the best client. People may already be logged into the system before they hit the angular site, or they may hit the angular site directly. the angular site is backed by .net core 2 services.

Comment: Implicit flow requires to show a view, so how you planning to do that? Use `password` grant-type, then it works with any Identity-Server. As far as I know IdentityServer doesn't provide a pop-up solution for authentication like Google or other OAuth providers. Maybe this will also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797446/identityserver3-implicit-flow-how-to-obtain-token

Comment: Thanks. the ID4 version uses implicit_flow and it works, when someone access the site it redirects to identity, which directs the user to a login page.

However this is my first real attempt to understand identity, so I may well be missing somethign key if it works with id4 but I cannot make it work in id3. Simply changing the authority and redirect url's hasn't worked, so I guess I need to dig deeper, now I know it is possible

Comment: Are the client configurations correct? Having same flows? Does your ID3 implement that login interface? That's not a built in feature.

Comment: Added some more information in the original post.

Comment: By implicit I assume you are using some kind of OIDC or OAuth flow?  There are a myriad of ways that identity server can be configured.  Is your app trying to get the user's identity or just an access token?

Comment: I have got it to authenticate a user now, however when the user logs in, there is no data displayed, (no welcome message, user profile etc). So I assume that I am part of the way there. So now I need to dig into the guts of it and see where the identity data is stored / passed, adn why it is not there in id 3 but it is in id4

However this is getting away from the original question, so I probably ought to close this topic.